# Flutter Range Slider Thumb Not Moving

Tags: ios, flutter, slider, range, flutter-layout

I have used Flutter Range Slider in my app. It is not moving. It does update the values when i try to move it in the onChanged method but the thumbs are not moving.

```
RangeValues _priceRangeValues = RangeValues(0, 100);
int minPrice = 0;
int maxPrice = 0;
Container(
              child: SliderTheme(
                data: SliderThemeData(
                  thumbColor: AppColors.kGreenColor.shade900,
                  activeTrackColor: AppColors.kPrimaryColor.shade900,
                  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                child: RangeSlider(
                  values: _priceRangeValues,
                  min: _priceRangeValues.start,
                  max: _priceRangeValues.end,
                  divisions: 100,
                  labels: RangeLabels(
                    '${_priceRangeValues.start.round().toString()} k',
                    '${_priceRangeValues.start.round().toString()} k',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                    print('price ${_priceRangeValues.start.round()}, ${_priceRangeValues.end.round()}');
                    _priceRangeValues = values;
                    minPrice = values.start.round();
                    maxPrice = values.end.round();
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: Thumbs are stuck!]

I have initialised the range outside the build method. Is there a solution available?

Answer (score 0):

As per your codes, you updated the _priceRangeValues and assigned it to the RangeSlider's min and max values. Can you please provide min and max values by default like `min: 0` and `max: 100`.

And also RangeSlider's onChanged callback will be disabled to the following cases:

- `onChanged` is null.
- `min` and `max` values is empty.
- `min` and `max` values is equal.

For more details : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html