# Flutter Range Slider in showModalBottomSheet not updating UI

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet, statefulwidget

So I have this `showModalBottomSheet()` and in it I have a couple widgets that require state, so I wrapped with `StatefulBuilder()`. Even though the other widgets are updating their data and UI as expected but the `RangeSlider()` does not update the UI(slide), it only updates the data.

I've tried wrapping the `RangeSlider()` with `StatefulBuilder()` but still it does not work(slide). I've also tried other solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846014/flutter-range-slider-thumb-not-moving)
How can I solve this issue.

Here is my code snippet

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
  top: Radius.circular(12.0),)),
  builder:(_){
  
  return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setter){
    return SafeArea(
    child: Column(
     children:[
       ...
Wrap(
  children: List.generate(1, (index) {
    final selectable = facets[index];
    final facet = selectable.item;
    RangeValues _currentRangeValues = RangeValues(0, double.parse(facets.last.item.value));
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
        thumbShape: const RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15),
      ),
      child: RangeSlider(
        min: 0,
        max: double.parse(facets.last.item.value),
        activeColor: AppColors.secondaryThemeColor,
        inactiveColor: AppColors.fontHeaderColor,
        labels: RangeLabels(
          _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString().replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
          _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString().replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
        ),
        values: _currentRangeValues,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            sVal = value.start.round();
            sFal = value.end.round();
            _currentRangeValues = value;
            facetPriceList.toggle(facet.value);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
      }),
     )       ...
      ]
     )
   );
  }


 }

)
```

And here is the screenshots

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling `setState` and this will update the main class, if you want to update inside `StatefulBuilder` you need to call StatefulBuilder's `setState`, first change your `StatefulBuilder` to this:

```
StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, innerSetState) {
  ...
}
```

then instead of `setState` call `innerSetState` in RangeSlider's `onChanged`:

```
innerSetState(() {
        sVal = value.start.round();
        sFal = value.end.round();
        _currentRangeValues = value;
        facetPriceList.toggle(facet.value);
      });
```

also your main issue is you are define `_currentRangeValues` inside build method. Every time you update `_currentRangeValues` its getting reset and define again. because you only want the first item in `facets` you don't need `list. generate` remove it, and put the variable before return `StatefulBuilder` like this:

```
final selectable = facets[0];
final facet = selectable.item;
RangeValues _currentRangeValues = RangeValues(0, double.parse(facets.last.item.value));

return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, innerSetState) {
  return ....
}
```

then change your `wrap` widget to this:

```
Wrap(
  children: [
    SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
        thumbShape:
            const RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15),
      ),
      child: RangeSlider(
        min: 0,
        max: double.parse(facets.last.item.value),
        activeColor: AppColors.secondaryThemeColor,
        inactiveColor: AppColors.fontHeaderColor,
        labels: RangeLabels(
          _currentRangeValues.start
              .round()
              .toString()
              .replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
          _currentRangeValues.end
              .round()
              .toString()
              .replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
        ),
        values: _currentRangeValues,
        onChanged: (value) {
          innerSetState(() {
            sVal = value.start.round();
            sFal = value.end.round();
            _currentRangeValues = value;
            facetPriceList.toggle(facet.value);
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: @Davis I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: I've tried it, It does not work.

Comment: did you try the updated answer?

Comment: Yes I did. I understand that the `showModalBottomsheet` is a stateless widget and therefor adding a statefulbuilder will solve the issue. I only solves other parts but not the `RangeSlider`

Comment: can you explain why are you call List.generate only for one item?

Comment: Because I just needed an access to index

Comment: How could I access the index without creating a list?? Is it possible??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250428/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-davis).